# Parameters for Controller from Html.ActionLink

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

On the Home View I'm generating a number of links:

```
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            @foreach (var item in ViewBag.RegList)
            {
                <li>@Html.ActionLink((string)item.registryName, "Index", "Registry", new { item.registryName }, new { item.registryID }) </li>
            }
        </ul>
```

I don't get - how do I set params in ActionLink for my controller and where they go from there?

That's how I defined Index in me controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(object attr)
```

But in attr goes only object, which when casted to string becomes null. If the orgignal type is string - then also null.

How do I transfer a parameter? Or I'm casting value to the wrong type?

Also I don't understand - what must fourth parameter of ActionLink (routeValues) be?

Method that I'm using: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972(v=vs.108).aspx

Or this one: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493068(v=vs.108).aspx

Comment: Its `new { attr =  item.registryName }` for the the 4th parameter and the method will be `public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string attr)` (and the 5th parameter is for adding html attributes and also needs to follow the same format

Comment: And how do I get those html attributes from 5th param to my controller?

Comment: You don't - its for adding html attributes, for example to add a class name to the link it wold be `new { @class = "form-control" }`. I assume you want to pass multiple parameters to the method, it which case the 4th parameter would be `new { someParameterName + Item.SomeProperty, anotherParameterName = item.AnotherProperty }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the created link they will contain a set of query string parameters

```
     "https://some.where/controller/SomeAction/7788?extraParam1=foo&extraParam2=bar"
```

The standard routing config of MVC makes the parameter "id" part of the local path ("7788" in the example), whereas additional parameters are added to the query string (after the question mark).

Your method signature to the action should be something like

```
public async Task<ActionResult>
           SomeAction(string id, string extraParam1, string extraParam2)
```

to get the parameters in my example link.

Comment: OP can eventually just rename the `attr` of his action to `id`, or change the default parameter name to `attr`

Comment: You are right, but the question was how to access the values so I think a little more explanation was appropriate.

Comment: Oh, so the name of parameter in controller matters. Thank you so much